# Need to add class to div on hover of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `div` with the same class. Each div contains other divs, `.header`, `.body`, `.footer`. When I hover on one of the elements inside one div, for example `.header`, I need to add/remove a class on the another `.footer` element inside the same div.

The problem is when I hover one `.header` - I'm adding class to all `.footer` elements inside all other div's but I need to add new class only to the `.footer` inside the current div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header').hover(function() {
    $('.footer').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $('.footer').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use CSS for this, not JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing it relative to `this` (which is the current hovered header) and you can use [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) if that is the only footer in the grouping:

```js
$('.header').hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.footer').addClass('active');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.footer').removeClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header"> header </div>
    <div class="body"> body </div>
    <div class="footer"> footer </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header"> header </div>
    <div class="body"> body </div>
    <div class="footer"> footer </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header"> header </div>
    <div class="body"> body </div>
    <div class="footer"> footer </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `:hover` pseudo in CSS and the general sibling combinator selector `~`

```css
.list_item:hover .header:hover ~ .footer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header">Hover me</div>
    <div class="body">B</div>
    <div class="footer">F</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header">Hover me</div>
    <div class="body">B</div>
    <div class="footer">F</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header">Hover me</div>
    <div class="body">B</div>
    <div class="footer">F</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

otherwise, if you cannot rely on `.footer` being a next sibling - use jQuery

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $('.header').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.list_item').find('.footer').toggleClass('active');
  });
    
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header">Hover me</div>
    <div class="body">B</div>
    <div class="footer">F</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header">Hover me</div>
    <div class="body">B</div>
    <div class="footer">F</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="header">Hover me</div>
    <div class="body">B</div>
    <div class="footer">F</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes can try below code snippet, I have tested it already.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.header').hover(function(){     
        $(this).siblings(".footer").addClass('active');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $(this).siblings(".footer").removeClass('active');      
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add different ID property all some div, get `$('#footer3')` and change it

Comment: No. This is literally the worst approach to solve this problem.